# Fazer debug pelo chrome de objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Coloco um break point em minha função `javascript(F9)` e depois dou `F12` no `chrome` com a aplicação aberta. Aperto um botão que vai chamar essa função por exemplo e não para no break. Não consigo ver o que cada variável, parâmetro está sendo passado. Como eu faço isso? No `IE`, eu consigo, apesar de que com o debug de script "ligado" e ficar dando aqueles erros de script, mas consigo. Gostaria de conseguir no `Chrome`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta confundindo o Debug pela `IDE` de Desenvolvimento com o Debug atraves do `Chrome DevTools`.

para criar o Breakpoint, use o `F12` para abrir o `Chrome DevTools`, vá para à aba `Source`, olhe a lista de sources e procure o JavaScript que deseja fazer o debug, então coloque o breakpoint do lugar desejado.

Um fluxo alternativo seria carregar a pagina com o `Chrome DevTools` aberto, na Aba `Network` filtrar por `Documents` e/ou `Scripts`, localizar o arquivo desejado, `right-click`,`Open in Source-panel`.

Caso deseje fazer o debug usando alguma IDE como o VS, você deve abrir a aplicação com o `Internet Explore`.

Comment: Como eu vejo o valor de uma variável ou parâmetro no debug do chrome. Tenho assim: var AbrirModal = function (url, title, width, height) {
        dialog.attr("src", url);
        dialog.dialog("option", "title", title);
        dialog.dialog("option", "width", width);
        dialog.dialog("option", "height", height);
    } aí eu quero saber o valor do parâmetro url, por exemplo. Coloco o mouse em cima, mas não me vem nada. Não consigo obter o valor do parâmetro.

Comment: colocou o breakpoint dentro do método?

Comment: Sim, coloquei e quero pegar o valor das variáveis ou parâmetros e nada.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem certeza que o breakpoint está colocado corretamente no seu código? Se você usar um `console.log` naquele local ele vai escrever certinho?

Se estiver tudo ok, tente ao invés de usar o breakpoint manual do chrome colocar um [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) no seu código, e qualquer browser deve parar naquela linha.